# How can I use RStudio on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, rstudio

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.04 (Disco Dingo). 
After the upgrade, I always failed to open RStudio. However, base R is still working on terminal.
Out of curiosity, I visited RStudio [download page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), and to my surprise, I did not find the installer for RStudio for Ubuntu 19.

Does anyone know how I can get RStudio working on my Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: There is a v1.2-patch on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/milestones). If this doesn't work, you'll need to wait for v1.3, but there is no set release date at present. Otherwise, you'll need to run Ubuntu 18 in a VM - not ideal, but probably better than down-grading your Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

After installing rstudio on 19.04 I add the message "dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio: rstudio depends on libclang-dev; however: Package libclang-dev is not installed"

So I  `apt-get install libclang-dev`

and then I run in more unmet dependencies.

So, as suggested I run `apt --fix-broken install`

which corrected dependencies and installed several packages.

So I re run

`dpkg -i rstudio-1.2.5001-amd64.deb`

and now everything works fine

hopping this can help ...

Answer (score -1):

I just tried these steps and it worked for me

step1: make a supper user from your terminal

```
    "sudo -i"
```

step2: start rstudio from terminal
         "rstudio"

At this point, the Rstudio IDE has started working.
That is it.

Comment: Running arbitrary programs with root privileges is not a good advice.